# Could not initialize class com.ebay.sdk.SdkAPIInterfaceServiceLocator JAVA

Tags: java, ebay-api

I am using Java eBay SDK, and I am trying to call `addItem` API, I added eBay maven dependency and repository and wrote a simple application that adds a new `Item`. The main is as shown below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    App aai = new App();
    try {
        ItemType item = aai.buildItem();
        FeesType fees;
        AddItemCall call = new AddItemCall(aai.apiContext);
        call.setItem(item);
        call.setAutoSetItemUUID(true);

        fees = call.addItem();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I keep getting this error that i couldn't fix:

```
[main] INFO com.ebay.sdk.SdkAPIInterfaceServiceLocator - loading wsdl : jar:file:/home/mss/.m2/repository/ebaysdkcore/ebaysdkcore/943/ebaysdkcore-943.jar!/eBaySvc.wsdl

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.ebay.sdk.SdkAPIInterfaceServiceLocator
at com.ebay.sdk.ApiCall.executeByApiName(ApiCall.java:594)
at com.ebay.sdk.ApiCall.execute(ApiCall.java:348)
at com.ebay.sdk.call.AddItemCall.addItem(AddItemCall.java:162)
at org.ecommerce_eBay.App.main(App.java:38)
```

Does anyone have any idea about it? 
Thank you !

Comment: would you please share the maven dependency you added?

Comment: the repo is: 
  <repository>
   <id>ebaysdkcore-repo</id>
   <url>https://raw.github.com/prestonvanloon/ebaysdkcore/mvn-repo/</url>
  </repository>
end the dependency is:                                                                                                
  <dependency>
   <groupId>ebaysdkcore</groupId>
   <artifactId>ebaysdkcore</artifactId>
   <version>943</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error with Java 11. Just add the following dependencies into the maven file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ebay</groupId>
        <artifactId>ebaysdkcore</artifactId>
        <version>1055</version>
        <version>1085</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ebay</groupId>
        <artifactId>ebaycalls</artifactId>
        <version>1055</version>
        <version>1085</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

Java 11 dont have the **com.sun.xml.ws** dependencies anymore -> Therefore, we need to add them explicitly.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- JAXWS for Java 11 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer. Could you add some text that explains your solution?